# Propercase function with hypens

Tags: vb.net, casing

I've got a `ProperCase` function in my .Net code like so

```
Public Function ProperCase(ByVal strValue As String) As String
    Dim outString As String = ""
    Dim badWords As String = "and, at, do, de, du, USA, UK"
    Dim splitter(1) As Char
    splitter(0) = " "
    Dim splitString As String() = strValue.Split(splitter)
    For Each s As String In splitString
        If badWords.Contains(s) Then
            outString = outString & s & " "
        Else
            outString = outString & StrConv(s, VbStrConv.ProperCase) & " "
        End If
    Next
    Return Trim(outString)
End Function
```

I need to propercase double barrelled names like `Taylor-Smith` but it's coming out like `Taylor-smith` because the splitter is a space so I modified the code like so.

```
Public Function ProperCase(ByVal strValue As String) As String
    Dim outString As String = ""
    Dim badWords As String = "and, at, do, de, du, USA, UK"
    Dim splitter(2) As Char
    splitter(0) = " "
    splitter(1) = "-"
    Dim splitString As String() = strValue.Split(splitter)
    For Each s As String In splitString
        If badWords.Contains(s) Then
            outString = outString & s
        Else
            outString = outString & StrConv(s, VbStrConv.ProperCase)
        End If
    Next
    Return Trim(outString)
End Function
```

So I added an extra splitter into the function but now it's not returning the value with the  hyphen in. I removed the `& " "` from the end of the outString but i'm not sure what I can replace it with.

I've tried to add `& splitter` but it always returns a hyphen even if the splitter was a space.

Currently I'm getting this with my modified code

`Mr TomHart`
`Mr JamieTaylorSmith`

And With the first version of the code I got this

`Mr Tom Hart`
`Mr Jamie Taylor-smith`

My expected outputs are like so...

`Mr Tom Hart`
`Mr Jamie Taylor-Smith`

Any ideas?

Comment: Sample inputs, outputs and expected outputs would help. I don't see the issue you are having.

Comment: @Oded I've updated with expected outputs - Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't alter the split method at all to catch the hyphens.  Instead I would look at the outstring. Resulting from your first method before you changed it. Probably in the If inside the loop.

This is a really quick idea to base it on... not necessarily the cleanest version of it but should give you the idea:

```
    Dim outstring As String = "Michael James-smith"
    Dim indexOfCharToCheck As Integer = outstring.LastIndexOf("-"c) + 1
    Dim finalString As String = outstring.Substring(0, indexOfCharToCheck) & UCase(outstring(indexOfCharToCheck).ToString) & outstring.Substring(indexOfCharToCheck + 1)
    MsgBox(finalString)
```

Comment: Thank you just what I was after